# Column class name change on a fly

Tags: slickgrid

I have rendered a grid that way:

```
myGrid = new Slick.Grid("#grid", myDataView, myColumns, myOptions);
myDataView.beginUpdate();
myDataView.setItems(myDataset);
myDataView.endUpdate();
```

it is ok.
Now i need to change css class name in certain column. I do:

```
myGrid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    args.sortCol.headerCssClass = 'newClassName';
});
```

What i need to do now to see changes in DOM?

---

I found this solution:

```
myGrid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    args.sortCol.headerCssClass = 'newClassName';
    var columns = myGrid.getColumns();
    myGrid.setColumns(columns);
});
```

Is this solution most elegant? Is there a proper method?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the style of the "sorted-by" header column. If this is indeed the case, why don't you modify the *slick-header-column-sorted* CSS selector?

For instance, the following rule would bold the title of the "sorted-by" header column:

```
.slick-header-column-sorted 
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I need to do multiple sorting styles for columns.